# Why don't ferrous metals fall to earth faster than other objects?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

Given that gravity is a weak force compared with magnetism and given the fact that the earth is a magnet, why don't ferrous metals fall to earth faster than other objects? Seems like they should!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 4):

The force exerted by the magnetic field of the earth on a chunk of iron at its surface is far weaker than the force of gravity. (Also, note that because of the shape of the earth's magnetic field, any attractive force between it and a piece of ferrous metal would be concentrated at the earth's north and south magnetic poles.)

Comment: In this context instead of saying the magnetic field is "concentrated" near the poles, it's better (and also more accurate) to say that the vertical component of the field has more strength compared to equatorial regions.

Comment: Two points. 1) If I drop and apple to the earth, the apple falls toward the earth, but the earth also falls toward the apple. It may not be measurable but it does. So saying that the force is weaker doesn't answer the question. 2) If the magnetic field is concentrated at the polls, does this mean that the ferrous material will fall faster at the polls?

Comment: @JonVote, I'm spending my time building portable handwashing stations for the homeless here in Oregon and it may be a while before I answer any but the easy questions here. sorry!